# How to parameterize concatenated string queries in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core, I can parameterize an SQL query like so:

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"select * from table where id = {myid}");
```

where the SQL query string is a `FormattableString`.

I need to run a SQL update for around 100 rows at a go and when I do using Linq, This makes 100 calls to the database, when I could easily do this using a SQL statement something like

```
UPDATE entity 
SET column = CASE .....
```

in a single call. But I am not sure how to go about doing this for concatenated strings.

For example:

```
string sqlQuery = "UPDATE entity SET column = CASE " 

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    sqlQuery += "WHEN column2 = i THEN i + 1 ";
}

sqlQuery += "WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)";

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sqlQuery);
```

How can I sanitize or parameterize this query? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your first example is a *bad* way to parameterise your query as it opens you up to SQL injection: The interpolated strings feature in C# is not set up specifically for SQL commands; it's intended to have a variety of uses and thus does not implement SQL sanitisation.</s>

You should always use the `SqlCommand` class and its `Parameters` property to ensure that your parameters are properly sanitised:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_Parameters

Update: The interpolated string is implicitly treated as a SQL command and the interpolands sanitised when using that specific constructor in EF Core.

However, in this case, you will need to build your string using @ parameter notation and then substitute the parameters using `SqlCommand` to ensure they are sanitised, since you can't represent the query as a single template literal.

Also, if you do ever need to concatenate a large number of strings, += is a very inefficient way of doing so, you should use `StringBuilder` instead for speed.

Comment: Thanks. I can assure you that the code `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($"select * from table where id = {myid}");` is safe, maybe not best practice but its a `FormattableString` class not a normal string and therefore is parameterized by Entity Framework. The problem is actually with concatenation - when I concatenate, as shown in my example, I can no longer pass it as a FormattableString to the ExecuteSQLCommandAsync method. Do you have any suggestions on how I can make that happen?

Comment: Create your string with a StringBuilder (for performance) and instead of directly replacing in {i} and {i+1} replace in something like @i_0. Then create a SqlCommand from the string and run a loop that adds parameters to replace each of the values in the parameterised query.

Comment: Looks like you've missed EF Core tag. The first example is *perfectly valid* for EF Core SQL commands because EF Core treats interpolated strings specially and binds parameter for each placeholder.

Comment: That's some very sneaky implicit behaviour. Accidentally using it in previous versions of EF seems like an easy trap to fall into.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure how I can concatenate the string while still being able to parameterize it(because `FormattableString` class doesn't support concatenation), unless I do some reflection... is there a way?

Comment: When using SqlCommand you don't need to use a FormattableString. You use a plain string with your variables marked as something like "@variableName". For example: `var query = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM Fruits WHERE Name = @variableName");`. Then you call `mySqlCommand["@variableName"].Value = aValueThatWillBeSanitized;` and your value will be substituted in everywhere that @variableName appears, with full sanitization. Neither your query string nor your values need to be a FormattableString in this case for the sanitization to work.